# Opening Vensim Models on Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, vensim

I am having trouble importing a Vensim Model (Version 9.3) on Anylogic. I get the error -  "parsing error! com.anylogic.ui.bad: encountered " ","","" at line X , column Y, was expecting: <V_LINE_BREAK>..." I tried to see if I can download older Vensim version, but it wasn't possible.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that AnyLogic supports import for models created with Vensim 7 or older versions. It might be incompatibility problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug

you can do it with vensim up to version 7, but with vensim 8 or higher it's impossible to import models

I reported this problem to AnyLogic.

Response from AnyLogic:

> Our converter was written several years ago, and we do not maintain
> compatibility with newer versions of Vensim.They have updated file
> format, and we need to research it, and update our converter. This is
> not a taks with high priority. Vensim 8 support will be added in next
> versions (8.8 or later).